# Como habilitar un botón en un horario específico JS

Tags: javascript, html5

estoy trabajando con un botón a través de un componente LitElement....
Necesito habilitar un botón dentro del siguiente horario de 9 am a 2:30 pm....

Tengo el siguiente código, un método que que me genera el botón cuando renderiza la pagina con la propiedad para habilitarlo y deshabilitarlo, y otro en donde tengo la validación del horario, éste en ocasiones me habilita el botón dentro del horario especificado y otras veces no...Ayuda...

El método para habilitar el botón lo ejecuto en el firstUpdated (ciclo de vida del componente)

```js
 _disabledBtn() {
    let min = this.toDay.getMinutes();
    let hrs = this.toDay.getHours();
    let sgds = this.toDay.getSeconds();
    let hora = `${hrs}:${min}:${sgds}`
    if (hrs <= 8) {
      console.log('hrs <= 8 btn deshabilitado');
      this.btnDisabled = true
    } else if (hrs >= 9) {
      console.log('hrs >= 9 btn habilitado', 'Hora Actaual', hora);
      this.btnDisabled = false
      if (hrs <= 14 && min <= 30) {
        console.log('hrs <= 14 && min <= 30 btn habilitado', 'Hora Actaual', hora);
        this.btnDisabled = false
      } else {
        console.log('hrs >= 14 && min >= 30 btn deshabilitado', 'Hora Actaual', hora);
        this.btnDisabled = true
      }
    } else {
      console.log('no entre en ninguna validacion', 'Hora Actaual', hora)
      this.btnDisabled = true
    }

  }
```

```html
 get _btnDisabled() {
    return html`
        <button-default variant="positive" .disabled="${this.btnDisabled}"  @click="${this._goToListAccount}">
          <span class="span-btn">Buscar Información</span>
        </button-default>
    `;
  }
```

```js
firstUpdated() {
    console.log('FirstUpdated()')
    this._disabledBtn();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de comparar por pedazos compara por marca de tiempo:

```
var ini = new Date();
ini.setHours(9,0,0);
var fin = new Date();
fin.setHours(14,30,0);
var hoy = new Date();

console.log( '¿Dentro de horario?'
           , ini.getTime() <= hoy.getTime() && hoy.getTime() <= fin.getTime() 
           );
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario lo implemento...